# Recovery VM VMware vSphere

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

Please, tell me how to recreate correctly Virtual Machine, if I have following files on my hard drive:

- X.nvram
- X.vmdk
- X_1.vmdk
- X-flat.vmdk
- X_1-flat.vmdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the files you have there is no way to get the original configuration.

1. Create a new virtual machine
2. remove the new hard disk that is created by default
3. add a hard disk, select existing, select your file.

Comment: Thank you! But if i don't know what settings were used when creating this VM?

Comment: Make an educated guess. Or ask someone who might know.